# Specific and technical question closed on the grounds its opinion-based

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[My (yet answered) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430445/mpir-status-and-raison-d%C3%AAtre) has been closed on the grounds it’s opinion-based, but I'm unsure that is the case. It has attracted a few commenters that work with arbitrary-precision libraries.

[MPIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPIR_(mathematics_software)) is an arbitrary-precision library forked from [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), but it is now unmaintained. My intent is to study it and merge back any relevant and useful developments into GMP (if developers accept it, of course).

The question is very clear: I need to know what was the primary intent of the MPIR fork, and what the functionalities that MPIR contain that GMP does not.

Is this considered opinion-based?

Comment: That question is too broad and the first sub-question suffers from the same issue that's been discussed here [Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334)

Comment: Got it! So, the issue is the *why*, not the *what*. By the way, love the 'There is no "clean" answer to the question about why the particular sausage was made that way.' on the post, although I believe german saussage makers would have very specific answers for that type of question.

Comment: Ok, now I removed the why, and left only MPIR status and what are the features exclusive to it. Hope it is reopen, the arbitrary-precision community might benefit from an answer.

Comment: Your question is still off-topic. It is not about practical programming problem. SO is not the place you can go to ask general questions about libraries or their maintenance or even list of features. If you have programming problem you need to solve while using some library then you can ask it. Beyond that no. Not all questions that are of interest to developers are suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Indeed. When you have one problem you usually have two problems. But a question can only have one close reason on SO.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, ok, you explained well, that was not something I had in mind, but now to me its clear, the question is out of scope. There is one practical programming problem I had in mind, but it is of much broader scope. Should I delete the question, or leave as it is?

Comment: @Arc Since, you cannot edit that question to make it on topic, it would be best to delete it. Please note that downvoted questions count toward question ban. Deleted questions still count. But at this point deleting would prevent accumulating more downvotes which would be worse for you. I also suggest that you visit [help] and learn more about what is on-topic and off-topic.

Comment: You don't need to worry about downvotes on Meta posts because rules are different on the Meta and your participation on the main site will not be affected by Meta posts. On Meta upvotes and downvotes often signal agreement or disagreement with the post.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, ok thanks! I'm really getting nuked on that one :)

Comment: Arc, as others have said, that question is a bad fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A model. OTOH, there may be people on SO (or other coding sites on the network) that have relevant info, and would be happy to discuss this stuff with you in some chat room on the network. But it might take a while to find those people. [This search](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=MPIR) shows that there hasn't been a lot of MPIR discussion in the chat network.

Comment: @PM2Ring, ok, very nice, its good to know I can use the chat for that, I guess I underestimated it, and did not read enough before start using SO. I also did not know we can search chat and then invite users to chat, which is very useful. But now I know, thanks.

Comment: By the way, I saw many questions on how to directly contacting users on SO, but seen no answers about inviting them by the chat. Will contribute on that when appropriate.

Comment: I suggest you look for a room where discussing coding for GMP & MPIR may be on-topic, and then make a brief general announcement explaining what you want to do. In most chat rooms, it's considered bad etiquette to ping total strangers with questions &/or requests.

Answer (score 17):

It's opinion-based (and off-topic) because it's inviting speculation about someone's behavior rather than asking a specific programming question. Questions that invite speculation should be closed as opinion-based.

Also, it's unclear to me what the actual practical value of this information is. From the ["Don't Ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

This question is not practical, not answerable, and not about an actual problem that you face.

Comment: The problem that I face is an entire arbitrary-precision library gone dark without us knowing exactly why. Don't you think this is suitable knowledge for this site? At least to know the reasons why? Note that MPIR has its own [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpir) on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Arc if the answer is "because the maintainers are not interested in maintaining the library anymore (for whatever reasons they don't want to tell)", then what knowledge do we learn? Note that the existence of a tag doesn't mean anything related to it can be asked. Stack Overflow is about practical programming.

Comment: Hi @AndrewT., by diff comparing GMP and MPIR I found some important developments on arbitrary-precision arithmetic in MPIR that are not in GMP, since MPIR is unmaintained now, perhaps those improvements could be merged back into GMP, but I'm no specialist yet on those, so I'm studying to find out whether there's something that could be used from MPIR. That's why I asked the question, but I'm also going into the code to find out.

Comment: And the reasons why developers don't exactly coordinate between GMP and MPIR is something that is obviously out of my scope to question. There's a whole directory on fast Fourier transform on MPIR that isn't on GMP, so I want to understand what is it and why isn't it merged back into GMP.

Comment: "what is it and why isn't it merged back into GMP" are not practical programming questions, they are off-topic on SO. Not every question is a SO question.

Comment: Ok, I have been enlightened about SO scope, question deleted. Thanks all.